# BlueZ bluetoothctl on Raspbian Jessie, connecting a Raspberry Pi to a Sphero

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspbian, bluez, sphero

When trying to connect to a Sphero (from Orbotix) through Bluetooth, on a Raspbian Jessie fully updated:

- if I do (being root, with Sphero paired and trusted)

  `# bluetoothctl
  [bluetooth]# connect {sphero-mac-address}
  [CHG] Device {sphero-mac-address} Connected:yes
  [CHG] Device {sphero-mac-address} Connected:no`

  As you can see the connection fails
- but if I do instead

  `# rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm0 {sphero-mac-address}
  Connected /dev/rfcomm0 to {sphero-mac-address} on channel 1`

The connection succeeds, and the Sphero appears connected in bluetoothctl also, afterwards.

What do I do wrong with `bluetoothctl` `connect`?

Answer (score 1):

i have the same phenomenom on raspberry pi 3 Jessie when i forgot to do 

`pulseaudio --start`

before `bluetoothctl`